# React-Redux:reducer only return initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

when i using redux in my react app,reducer just return initial state for me.which is  always returned the false here.thanks for your answer.

[UPDATE]:
i chaned

```
let newState = state
```

to this:

```
 let newState = {...state}
```

but also reducer returned false

this my reducer:

```
 const initialState = {
      modalVisible: false
    };
    function modalReducer(state = initialState, action) {
      let newState = {...state};
      switch (action.type) {
        case "SHOW":
          newState.modalVisible = true;
          console.log("Show!");
          break;
        case "HIDE":
          newState.modalVisible = false;
          console.log("Hide!");
          break;
      }
      return newState;
    }

export default modalReducer;
```

and this is my component (Svg Viewer component)

```
import React from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";

const SvgViewer = ({
  nodesData,
  svgFilePath,
  modalVisible,
  onModalShow,
  onModalHide
}) => {

  const clickHandler = () => {
    onModalShow();
    console.log(modalVisible); //return false
    onModalHide();
    console.log(modalVisible);
  };

  return (
    <div className="unit-schema-container1" key={svgFilePath}>
      <object id="svgobject" type="image/svg+xml" data={svgFilePath}></object>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}></button>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { modalVisible: state.modalVisible };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onModalShow: () => {
      dispatch({ type: "SHOW" });
    },
    onModalHide: () => {
      dispatch({ type: "HIDE" });
    }
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SvgViewer);
```

Comment: The update from the store is async, so you won't see it with a `console.log` just after.

Comment: You have both show and hide click event in a single OnClick function. So when you click on the button its  make show and hide async update without any changes. Please separate the show and hide click event to see the changes. or put a 1-2s timeout function after onModalShow() function.

Comment: i did it, but dose not work

Answer (score 3):

You should try using this. Its easier to read and uses the best practices

```
const initialState = {
  modalVisible: false
};

function modalReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SHOW":
      return {...state, modalVisible: true }
    case "HIDE":
      return {...state, modalVisible: false }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should return a new state object

```
let newState = {...state}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in mapStateToprops function, please post your main reducer,
try to edit you mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { modalVisible: state.modalVisible.modalVisible  };
};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but not work.also now i have only one reducer

Comment: how do you create your store? with what parameters?

Comment: const store = createStore(modalReducer);